# Not able to find uninstall function

Tags: powershell

> Failed to call method because [Microsoft.PackageManagement.Packaging.SoftwareIdentity] does not contain a method named "uninstall".

Trying to uninstall a program called Citrix.

```perl
$myapp = Get-Package -Name 'Citrix 7.15*'
$myapp.uninstall()
```

Tried `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -match "*Citrix*"}` - but it waits for 2 minutes and then returns nothing.

PowerShell version 5.1.14409.1005

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-Package -Name 'Citrix 7.15*' | Uninstall-Package
```

Comment: It gives nothing still the software is there in the Apps and Programs list.

Somehow it was found that uninstall package is not installed. Correct module PackageManagement not installed.

Comment: Issue closed, thanks for your support

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it. If the issue was something else, please post it as an answer so it can help someone else who encounters the same problem. One way or another, you must accept an answer, or your question will stay in the system as unsolved forever.